# JxBrowser - Select All

Tags: java, swing, jxbrowser

In my Java Swing application, I have an embedded JxBrowser component. With this, I am building a right click context menu with all the usual commands: copy, paste, back, forward, refresh, and select all.

I am having difficulty with select all. I am able to manually hit ctrl-a to select all but I cannot figure out how to do this programmatically.

I have tried the following with no success:

```
                popupMenu.add(createMenuItem("Select All", new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    getView().grabFocus();
                    try {
                        Robot robot = new Robot();
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_A);
                        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
                    } catch (AWTException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }));

    private static JMenuItem createMenuItem(String title, final Runnable action) {
        JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(title);
        menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                action.run();
            }
        });
        return menuItem;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer.

```
browser.executeCommand(EditorCommand.SELECT_ALL);
```